# How can I test if a link is opened from my app using UIAutomation?

Tags: ios, functional-testing, ios-ui-automation

I have this app that has a login screen with fields for username and password. Below the fields there is this 'Forgot password link'. I am testing this app using UIAutomation class. How can I test if, when clicked on that link, the  linked page is opened in the browser? I just want to check that when the link is clicked, the browser is opened.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

if you make sure that before the UIAutomation clicks the link that the associated default browser is not open then you could just simply see if the process for the given browser is running after the click (perhaps after a wait of a second or so)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Probably my question was not clear enough. What I want to know is that how to check from instruments if the process for the browser is running or not? I mean what javascript code should I use to check if the browser is runninng or not?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do that. Instruments will only allow one target at a time so the script stops when the target is navigated away from.